# Ran over a curb at speed; wheel is bent and rubs against wheelwell on turns

Tags: suspension, wheels, steering

The other day I was doing 30 mph on a downhill road in my Renault Clio 1.2, and went to turn right, but my brakes did not work, and so I just turned into the corner and went straight into and up a 3-inch curb, which stopped me.

Now every time I turn, the front wheels rub on the car. My right side wheel is bent in at the top. The left side wheel looks fine, but slighty rubs when I turn. What do you think will need to be done?

Comment: While driving, does the wheel pull to the left or right? Does it feel different than it did before? I would bet you need to get an alignment done.

Comment: I think it pulls to the left a little bit, as the right wheel is pushed in at the top and the bottom is out. I can get the brakes sorted easy but do you think it will be safe to drive to a garage once they have been installed?

Comment: @Paulster2 See above

Comment: I cannot tell you one way or another. This is a judgement call you'd have to make. I really think you might have done some serious damage to the front end of the car, which also may include a bent rim. Getting the brakes sorted is only going to be part of the issue. If you get the brakes fixed, I'd have someone who knows cars take a look at it and give you that advice. It will more than likely require an alignment, but you may have other things going on as well.

Comment: Well I've inspected underneath the car, everything looks straight and nothin has snapped. The suspension looks fine but I cant really tell if it has moved in anyway. Also the right wheel is rubbing on the spring thing that's above the wheel when I turn either way.

Answer (score 1):

As you have a serious brake fault you will need to have the vehicle lifted to a garage for repair. A complete brake inspection and overhaul would be required, especially as you do not have a complete history of the vehicle having recently acquired it. Next step will be replacement of any bent wheels and possibly damaged tyres. This vehicle will also need an inspection of steering and suspension systems, together with a general check over for any other damage. The moral of this story is to have any vehicle you are concerned with, and have no way of knowing its true history, checked out by a competent garage/mechanic before trusting in it.

Comment: Likely the control arms are bent.  I've seen a few curb bounces with minimal or no rim damage, yet significant suspension arm damage.